# Facing issues working with GET request

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, get, python-requests

When I run my first script it fetches results but when I run my second script, I get nothing. I do't find anything missing in my second script to get the required results. The url used in the first script is concatenated with the requirement which I found in the developer tool. Why ain't my second script working when I use the base url along with parameter?

```
import requests
from lxml import html
response = requests.get("http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_trksid=p2050601.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xfunny+bear.TRS0&_nkw=funny+bear&_sacat=237")
tree=html.fromstring(response.text)
titles=tree.xpath("//h3[@class='lvtitle']")
for title in titles:
    name=title.xpath(".//a[@class='vip']/text()")[0]
    print(name)

import requests
from lxml import html
payload={'_from':'R40','_trksid':'p2050601.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xfunny+bear.TRS0','_nkw':'funny+bear','_sacat':'237'}
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get("http://www.ebay.com/",data=payload,headers=headers)
tree=html.fromstring(response.text)
titles=tree.xpath("//h3[@class='lvtitle']")
for title in titles:
    name=title.xpath(".//a[@class='vip']/text()")[0]
    print(name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your URL is `http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html`. (not just ebay.com)

Then, if you wanted to build a query string like `wwww.example.com?key1=value1&key2=value2`, you need to use `params` as the parameter rather than `data`.

This code should work.

```
import requests
from lxml import html
payload = {'_from':'R40','_trksid':'p2050601.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Xfunny+bear.TRS0','_nkw':'funny+bear','_sacat':'237'}
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.81 Safari/537.36'}
response = requests.get("http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html", params=payload, headers=headers)
tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
titles = tree.xpath("//h3[@class='lvtitle']")
for title in titles:
    name = title.xpath(".//a[@class='vip']/text()")[0]
    print(name)
```

Reference: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls

Comment: Thanks Ernie, for your quick and effective solution. One thing to know: How can I get the accurate url? Looking into the url in your script you can see that it has been used in the first script in my post with some required fields concatenated with it.

Comment: @SMth80 
Usually, the URL and query string are split by char `?`.
For a given URL like `https://www.example.com/path1/path2?key1=value1&key2=value2`, `https://www.example.com/path1/path2` is the accurate URL points to a certain resource(web page) or HTTP API, `key1=value1` and `key2=value2` are query conditions you need to put into `params`.

Comment: Thanks Ernie for everything.